# TCustomADODataSet catching EOleException (not EDatabaseError)

Tags: delphi, ado

In some situation (in a multi-user environment) when I `Edit` a `TADODataSet` and `Post` it, I get an Exception raised by ADO:

> "Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed
>   since it was last read."

If I run my program from the IDE the exception is raised as `EOleException` with Error number `-2147217864`.
I want to be able to catch this exception, but when I run the program outside the IDE the exception is raised as `EDatabaseError` which does not have the `ErrorCode` I need to examine. Here is part of my code:

```
procedure TForm1.DataSetCommit(ds: TADODataSet);
begin
  ds.Connection.BeginTrans;
  try    
    try
      ds.Post; // <- Exception is raised here
    except
      on E: EOleException do; // EOleException is NOT fired! (E.ErrorCode = -2147217864) - see "ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalPost"
      on E: EDatabaseError do 
      begin
        // todo: Handle this situation
      end;
    end;
    ds.Connection.CommitTrans;
  except
    ds.Connection.RollbackTrans;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

If you look in `ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalPost` you will notice that it's wrapped  as so:

```
procedure TCustomADODataSet.InternalPost;
begin
  UpdateCursorPos;
  try
    ... // <- Exception is raised here
  except
    on E: Exception do
      DatabaseError(E.Message);
  end;
  CheckForFlyAway;
end;
```

The exception is raised inside the local procedure `UpdateData`: `Recordset.Update(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);` which triggers a `EOleException` (what I need) but the wrapper raises `EDatabaseError`! (grrrrrrr).

My question is how do I get my hands on the original `EOleException` so I can query `EOleException.ErrorCode`?

Comment: Now that you shown RTL code, I think you can try either binary patching that procedure in memory, or hijacking RTL's ExceptProc to do address filtering and preventing this conversion from happening by wrapping EOLEException into your own class with formalized message text (like json) including all the parameters you need.

Comment: EOleException object is freed by TCustomADODataSet.InternalPost. I don't think you had changed to find it on stack. Glad that you solved it

Comment: @Arioch'The, How can you tell it is freed?

Comment: @Arioch'The, If you can **prove** that the `EOleException` is freed/dead and there is no way to find it in the stack at the time when `ds.Post` exception is raised, please provide an answer to prove it, and I'll accept.

Comment: I cannot, for I don't have expert knowledge on SEH in Win32. But I tried to encapsulate the exception in my own nested-exception class in my own except-end block, and I got AV later. Because without calling `AcquireExceptionObject` (which ADO RTL does not) the incoming `E:Exception` instance is freed when going out of the except-end. I also think that stack of Win32 SEH raw data frames is already unrolled at the moment when EOleException (or any other) is raised initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to utilize the `System.RaiseList` to get the `TRaiseFrame.NextRaise` to no avail - I'm not getting the desired `EOleException`... So I found a rather elegant solution which is **specific** to my case (ADO) and does not rely on the RTL - I'm testing the `Errors` object of the `TADODataSet.Connection`:

```
procedure TForm1.DataSetCommit(ds: TADODataSet);
begin
  ds.Connection.BeginTrans;
  try      
    try
      ds.Post;
    except          
      on E: EDatabaseError do 
      begin          
        if Assigned(ds.Connection.Errors) and (ds.Connection.Errors.Count > 0) then
          with ds.Connection.Errors.Item[0] do
            // if (Number = -2147217864) then ...
            ShowMessage(Format('Number:%d; Source:%s; Description:%s; NativeError:%d; SQLState:%s',
              [Number, Source, Description, NativeError, SQLState]));
      end;
    end;
    ds.Connection.CommitTrans;
  except
    ds.Connection.RollbackTrans;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

This will be my solution to the specific problem, but I'm still interested in other ideas on how to trap the previous exception of `EOleException`.